# It is possible to avoid making condition in 12:00 time?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hello I have this code below to format `12 hrs` from my mvc3 controller to my jqgrid. I have a value of `null` from my database but it return `12:00` I want is if it is `null` I want to return a `blank space` or `blank`.

```
            string FitaIn1 = Convert.ToDateTime(req.FAIn1).ToString("hh:mm");
            string FitaOut1 = Convert.ToDateTime(req.FAOut1).ToString("hh:mm");
            string FitaIn2 = Convert.ToDateTime(req.FAIn2).ToString("hh:mm");
            string FitaOut2 = Convert.ToDateTime(req.FAOut2).ToString("hh:mm");
            string FitaCorIn1 = Convert.ToDateTime(req.FACorrectionIn1).ToString("hh:mm");
            string FitaCorOut1 = Convert.ToDateTime(req.FACorrectionOut1).ToString("hh:mm");
            string FitaCorIn2 = Convert.ToDateTime(req.FACorrectionIn2).ToString("hh:mm");
            string FitaCorOut2 = Convert.ToDateTime(req.FACorrectionOut2).ToString("hh:mm");
```

At the same time I encounter this problem i try this code below because the null value returns `12:00`

```
if (FitaIn1 == "12:00") { FitaIn1 = "00:00"; }
```

It is possible to `log-in / log-out` in `12:00` noon right?. I'm out of idea.

Comment: Why are you using `Convert.ToDateTime()`? are you date properties really all `string`? And you can always use `if (req.FAIn1 != null) { ...`

Comment: @StephenMuecke the req.FAIn1 the datatype is DATETIME in my sql

Comment: Then why are you converting it (its already `DateTime`). And why not just use a `[DisplayFormat]` attribute on your property?

Comment: @Uki, `HH:mm` will produce 24hr format while `hh:mm` will produce 12 hr format

Comment: @Nkosi yes i am aware of that.